# Update Entity Framework - Need Hotfixes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I read following article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/10/18/how-we-talk-about-ef-and-its-future-versions.aspx

As far i understand this article, NuGet wont help me to fix bugs in the Core Entity Framework shipped with .NET 4. Is there any update for the core EF?

I found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624 - but cant find a download

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Have you tried to do what they ask you to do? i.e. "Contact Microsoft Customer Service and Support to obtain the hotfix."

Comment: No - is there no easier way?
I'm not satisfied with POCO Change Tracking anymore. Lots of Voodoo is behind the scene which is not documented ... I thought Martin Fowlers "Enterprise Architecture" is outdated – but it seems that the basic concepts are the best ... As Amazon says – Frameworks doing 100 things suck!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hot fixes to any part of .NET frameworks are only shipped in .NET Framework updates, service packs or in separate KB fixes - these fixes are either publicly available or distributed only if you ask MS to provide the fix. This one belongs to the last category and it is described directly in the article so your question together with your last comment belongs to category "Not a real question - just frustrated rant". Even we can agree with you we cannot help you with it.

Comment: Your are right - I'm frustrated :-) But I found a workaround. Back to Linq2SQL at next project ;)

Comment: Omg, maybe you should try something different? NHibernate or NoSql approach?